# Difficulty in understanding number of patches in an image in research paper

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to understand a paper on **Shadow Detection** ([link](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~minhhoai/papers/scGAN_ICCV17.pdf)).

In **Section 3.4**, the authors mention that, given an image, they create a batch of training instances, where the batch consists of :-

1. The original image resized to 256 × 256 pixels.
2. Patches 3/4 the size of the original image, extracted
   with a stride of 20, down sampled to 256 × 256.
3. 256 × 256 patches of the original image, sampled with
   a stride of 20.

On an average they get 13 training instances/patches per image.

If I understand properly they have used a function `tf.extract_image_patches` with ksizes as `[1, 0.75*image_height, 0.75*image_width, 1]` and `[1, 256, 256, 1]` for part 2 and 3 mentioned above respectively and strides as `[1, 20, 20, 1]`.

I tried running the above function with the mentioned `ksizes` and `strides`, but I get an average of 267 patches per image from the training data. More than **90%** of the images have `height` and `width` above **300** respectively. The paper has used **SBU Shadow Dataset** ([link](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~cvl/dataset.html)).

So I am not sure how come the authors claim to have just an average of 13 patches per image.

Any help here would help me expedite my reading and understanding of the paper.

Thanks in advance